# EF Core fluent config "DbUpdateConcurrencyException"

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

There are a few questions out there about the following exception, but I can't find any that match my scenario.

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException : The
> database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually
> affected 0 row(s); data may have been modified or deleted since
> entities were loaded. See
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on
> understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.

I converted my code to use simple names and properties to simplify things. I have two classes with one-to-many relationships. One is abstract and must be inherited, the other is a concrete class. For simplicity's sake `PieSlice` has the same structure as `FruitSlice`

```
public class Pie
{
    public string Name {get; set;}

    private IList<PieSlice> _slices;
    public  IList<PieSlice> Slices
    {
        get { return _slices; }
        set { _slices= value; }
    }
}

public abstract class Fruit
{
    private virtual IList<FruitSlice> _slices;
    public  virtual IList<FruitSlice> Slices
    {
        get { return _slices; }
        set { _slices= value; }
    }

    private FruitTypes _fruitType;
    public virtual FruitTypes FruitType
    {
        get { return _fruitType; }
        private set { _fruitType = value; }
    }

    public virtual int? SliceCount
    {
        get { return (int?)null; }
    }
}

public class FruitSlice
{
   public int Size {get; set;}
}    

public class PieSlice
{
   public int Size {get; set;}
}
    
public class Apple : Fruit
{
    public string Name {get; set;}

    public override FruitTypes FruitType
    {
        get { return FruitTypes.Apple; }
    }

    public override int? SliceCount
    {
        get { return Slices != null ? Slices.Count : 0; }
    }
}
```

On the EF config side, I have the following:

```
public class PieConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Pie>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Pie> modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ToTable("Pie");

         modelBuilder
             .HasMany(c => c.Slices)
             .WithOne(t => t.Pie)
             .HasConstraintName("FK_PieSlice_Pie")
             .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    }
}

public class FruitConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Fruit>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Fruit> modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ToTable("Fruit");
        modelBuilder.HasDiscriminator(d => d.FuitType)
            .HasValue(typeof(Apple), FuitTypes.Apple)

         modelBuilder
             .HasMany(c => c.Slices)
             .WithOne(t => t.Fruit)
             .HasConstraintName("FK_FruitSlice_Fruit")
             .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{

    modelBuilder.Entity<Apple>()
        .Ignore(b => b.SliceCount);
}
```

I create a new `Apple` and give it a couple of slices

```
Apple apple = new Apple();
apple.Name = "Fred";
FruitSlice slice1 = new FruitSlice();
slice1.Size = 1;
apple.Slices.Add(slice1);

_context.Add(apple);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

Essentially the same code to create/save a `Pie`

When I save a new `Pie`, it generates the correct SQL:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT INTO [Pie] ([column1, column2, ...])
VALUES (@p0, @p1 etc)'

exec sp_executesql N'SET NOCOUNT ON;
MERGE [PieSlice] USING (
VALUES (@p1, @p2..., 1)) AS i ([pie slice columns], _Position) ON 1=0
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT ([pie slice columns])
VALUES ([pie slice values])
OUTPUT INSERTED.[Id], i._Position;'
```

BUT when I save an `Apple`, I get the following

```
exec sp_executesql N'SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT INTO [Fruit] ([column1, column2, ...])
VALUES (@p0, @p1 etc)'
exec sp_executesql N'SET NOCOUNT ON;
UPDATE [FruitSlice] SET [FruitId] = @p64
OUTPUT 1
WHERE [Id] = @p65;
',N'@p65 int,@p64 int,',@p65=0,@p64=9573
```

The `FruitSlice` query is wrong and `WHERE Id = 0` is obviously not going to work (Id is a primary key, so will never be zero), but it has correctly inserted the Fruit and retrieved the new Id.

So my question is: Seeing as the SQL is generated for the Pie/Slices is correct and functional, how/why is the SQL for Apple/Slices incorrect?

The code to instantiate and save a `Pie` is exactly the same as instantiating and saving an `Apple`. So it has to be down to the `Apple` inheriting from the abstract `Fruit`, but I can't figure out what's causing the issue

**UPDATE**
I created a fleshed-out version of the above example and uploaded [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HO0VIMzNunNWt8gqYoSQJv6SUA_XhtiZ/view?usp=sharing) (in the unit test, I implemented both `_context.Add(apple)` and `context.Apple.Add(apple)` methods. ). Frustratingly, it works as it should. So a) it is not down to the inheritance, and b) there is clearly something else in my main project that is causing the problem.

In my actual project, the relationship structure is conceptually the same, and the child collections are configured the same. The class that inherits from an abstract class (like the `Apple`) will not save any child collections properly (as the above SQL queries show).

I'll have to strip it back and run the unit tests each time until it starts working, then build it back up.

Thanks!

**Update 2**
I resolved the issue :) I'm using the [Detached.Mappers](https://github.com/leonardoporro/Detached-Mapper) nuget package to do all the change tracking (which it does very well) and I was trying to move attributes in the domain into fluent configuration (Not a fan of attributes sprinkled all over the place). By putting a couple of those attributes back where they were, the exception ceased.

Comment: I assume that you `DbSet<Apple>`, fruit, slice, etc. and you didn't put those here for brevity. just wondering, can you try `context.Apple.Add(apple)` instead of `context.Add()`

Comment: Also where/how are your PKs defined? Your simplification may be concealing a possible problem with the actual entities/mapping. Take a simplified domain model that reproduces the actual issue at runtime and post that, if Pie works, leave that out, focus on what doesn't work and aim for a reproduceable example.

Comment: @Felix I have tried both `Add` variations. Yes, I do have `DbSet<Apple>` and did leave it out for brevity.

@StevePy both `Fruit` and `Pie` have `Id` as their PK and `FruitSlice` has `FruitId` as its FK and similarly, `PieSlice` has `PieId` as its FK. 

I'll build this out into a functional example and post it here